# What's the probable reason for linux tcp stack droping received packets?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have met a tcp network issue that the tcp packets were captured by tcpdump, but application can't read them. from the captured pcap file, I found that the packets are captured ( captured on receiving side, it means packets has reached the machine ), but there was no ack sent. It happened suddenly at a time, before that time everything is fine. I suspect these packets were dropped from ip layer to tcp layer, but don't know why. below is the screenshot of wireshark displaying.

[image]
[image]

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for reminding, have posted it at unix.stackexchange.com.